# Проблема в  CodeBlocks

Tags: codeblocks

Не хочет работать компилятор? пробовал через настройки Toolchain executables не помогло ,что делать

Answer (score 1):

Допустим, что я разбираюсь в Codeblocks. Тогда, учитывая количество подробностей, которое Вы предоставили, мой ответ будет приблизительно такой:

Нажмите кнопку с тремя точками справа от Auto-detect, и выберите директорию, в которую установлен ваш компилятор.

(*If not, then press the button with the three dots next to the "Auto-detect" button and select the installation directory of your compiler manually.*

*http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_a_supported_compiler*)

А вообще, это - вопрос на БитКод.